# Laravel Column not found: 1054 Unknown column

Tags: php, laravel

I need to get product list of user outlet but it returns this error

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '1' in 'on clause' (SQL: select * from `barcodes` inner join `outlet_products` on `1` = `outlet_products`.`outlet_id
```

## Logic

Get list of products of user outlet only (not all products from all outlets)

1. Product `basically just name and description` (has many barcodes)
2. Barcode (belongs to products, belongs to many outlets)
3. Outlet (has many barcodes)

## Code

```
$user = $request->user();
$outlets = $user->outlets->pluck('id');

$products = Barcode::with('product', 'damages', 'outlet')
  ->join('outlet_products', function ($join) use($outlets) {
    $join->on($outlets, '=', 'outlet_products.outlet_id');
  })
  ->get();
```

`Product model`

```
public function barcodes()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Barcode::class, 'product_id', 'id');
}
```

`Barcode model`

```
public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
}

public function outlet()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Outlet::class, 'outlet_products', 'barcode_id', 'outlet_id');
}
```

`outlet model`

```
public function barcodes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Barcode::class, 'outlet_products', 'outlet_id', 'barcode_id');
}
```

> Products of outlets are returning trough barcodes actually (outlet has many barcodes and each barcode belongs to a product).

**any idea?**

## Update

I've made some changes in my code and now is like this:

```
$products = Barcode::with('product', 'damages', 'outlet')
  ->join('outlet_users', 'outlet_users.user_id', '=', $user->id)
  ->join('outlet_products', 'outlet_products.outlet_id', '=',  'outlet_users.outlet_id')
  ->get();
```

now it returns this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '4' in 'on clause' (SQL: select * from `barcodes` inner join `outlet_users` on `outlet_users`.`user_id` = `4` inner join `outlet_products` on `outlet_products`.`outlet_id` = `outlet_users`.`outlet_id`)
```

> basically with this new function i am trying to get user outlet.id and match it with barcode (product) outlet.id.

Comment: That is not how joins work when using the query builder. It will cast it to column name. If you want to do it like that, then use where instead of join.

Comment: @Wesley-Synio wherehas on which part? `outlet_users` or `outlet_products`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on wrong way.
If you want to get lists of products of user outlet list

Update your outlet model with product_id.

On your way:

```
$user = $request->user();
$outlets = $user->outlets->pluck('id');

$products = Barcode::with('product','damages','outlet')
  ->whereHas('outlet', function ($q) use($outlets) {
    $q->whereIn('id',$outlets);
  })
  ->get();
```

Comment: it says `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select * from `barcodes` where exists (select * from `outlets` inner join `outlet_products` on `outlets`.`id` = `outlet_products`.`outlet_id` where `barcodes`.`id` = `outlet_products`.`barcode_id` and `id` in (1)))`

Comment: Then use 'outlets.id' instead of 'id' on the line with the `whereIn`

Comment: Please write all table names and model names

Comment: @Wesley-Synio unfortunately table name is not outlet :)

Comment: @ÖmerYilmaz yes with `$q->whereIn('outlets.id',$outlets);` works

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong:

`$join->on($outlets, '=', 'outlet_products.outlet_id');`

`$outlets` contains a list of ids, instead of a column name.

---

**Update:** A more direct approach to get all products for a particular user with the models defined like they are could be something like this:

```
$products = Product::whereHas('barcodes', function (Builder $barcodesQuery) {
  $barcodesQuery->whereHas('outlet', function (Builder $outletQuery) {
    $outletQuery->whereHas('users', function (Builder $userQuery) {
      $userQuery->where('id', $user->id);
    });
  });
})->get();
```

But you would have to add the reverse relationship `users()` to the `Outlet` model:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'outlet_users', 'outlet_id', 'user_id');
}
```

Untested...

Comment: Try adding the reverse relationship to the Outlet model to access the related User. That way you could get all Products that have a Barcode that have an Outlet where the User matches the current user. Could be done using `Model::whereHas()` although I would also add 'has-one-through' or 'has-many-through' relationships to the models so it's easier to query.

Comment: `has-one-through` or `has-many-through` would be useful if i want to get barcodes outlet trough product model but in my case is straight releationship between `barcodes` and `outlets` all i need is to add user validation to it so only user outlet barcodes would return